# How to get fingerprint from a pem file from Github App?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, private-key, github-app

It's possible to generate a private key for Github Apps (Settings -> Developer Settings -> (Edit a GH App) -> "Generate a private key"). When it's generated I save locally a **pem file** and in UI there's an information about fingerprint of that key (SHA256:...).

[image]

How can I receive that fingerprint myself in Java code, given the **pem file** that I saved before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pem file that you saved contains both information about private and public key, so it's possible to get that information yourself.

Information about verification of private keys is documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/managing-private-keys-for-github-apps) and it's basically the following one-line command:

```
openssl rsa -in PATH_TO_PEM_FILE -pubout -outform DER | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```

In order to get that information in Java, you can use **bouncycastle** library that does the same chain of operations as above.

```
public static String getFingerprint(final String pemContent) throws IOException {
    // openssl rsa -in PATH_TO_PEM_FILE -pubout -outform DER
    final PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(pemContent));
    final Object object = (PEMKeyPair) parser.readObject();
    final PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair) object;
    final SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = pemKeyPair.getPublicKeyInfo();
    final ASN1Primitive asn1Primitive = publicKeyInfo.toASN1Primitive();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    asn1Primitive.encodeTo(outputStream, "DER");
    final byte[] derBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

    // openssl sha256 -binary
    MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    instance.update(derBytes);
    byte[] sha256bytes = instance.digest();
    
    // openssl base64
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256bytes);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get the `-in` argument to work (even though it was documented in `--help`), so I had to use the command `openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER < /path/to/private_key.pem | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64`